# How to connect a React component to my Redux store using a selector that takes an argument in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I would like my component to select a portion of my state by providing an `id`, so I wrote a selector method like so:

```
const selectThing = (state: RootState, id: string) => state.things.get(id);
```

Then, to access the `id` in my `mapState`, I pass in my component's `Props`:

```
const mapState = (state: RootState, props: Props) => ({
  thing: selectThing(state, props.id)
})
```

However, when I connect everything [per the docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component), I am told that "`PropsFromRedux` circularly references itself", which makes sense because I am now feeding `PropsFromRedux` back through my `mapState` method, as it is extended by `Props`:

```
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux'

interface SomeComplicatedThing {
  //...
}

interface RootState {
  things: Map<string, SomeComplicatedThing>;
}

const selectThing = (state: RootState, id: string) => state.things.get(id);

const mapState = (state: RootState, props: Props) => ({
  thing: selectThing(state, props.id)
})

const mapDispatch = {
  //whatever
}

const connector = connect(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)

//PropsFromRedux circularly references itself
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>

interface Props extends PropsFromRedux {
  id: string
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => (
  <div>whatever</div>
)

export default connector(MyComponent)
```

Is there a better way to approach this? How do I connect up a component with a selector that takes an argument in Typescript? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just separate out your BaseProps from your Redux Props and then add them back in at the end. I'm not sure why the redux docs have it go into a circular reference in a fairly common usage of connect.

```
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';
import { type } from 'os';

interface SomeComplicatedThing {
  //...
}

interface RootState {
  things: Map<string, SomeComplicatedThing>;
}

const selectThing = (state: RootState, id: string) => state.things.get(id);
interface BaseProps {
  id: string;
}
const mapState = (state: RootState, props: BaseProps) => ({
  thing: selectThing(state, props.id),
});

const mapDispatch = {
  //whatever
};

const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch);

//PropsFromRedux circularly references itself
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;


const MyComponent = (props: PropsFromRedux & BaseProps) => {
return <div>whatever</div>};

export default connector(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Of course! Not sure why my background didn't lead me to think of that, but I'm a real n00b on the front end and am just rotely following docs at this point. Cheers

Comment: Also, thanks for your help as well, I hadn't actually heard of ConnectedProps yet. I missed it in the documentation when I was looking for pretty much exactly that earlier today!